# Find distance in graph with restrictions.

Tags: graph-theory

I have this task: there is a directed weighted graph of roads between cities. Some roads are with tunnels, some roads are without tunnels. We need to find the distance between two given cities with the following restriction: we cannot go through three roads with tunnels in a row (but two tunnels in the row, and then a road withouth tunnel is permitted). How can I solve this problem? I think that I should use Dijkstra's algorithm, but I have no idea how can I take into account the restriction with tunnels. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So you are looking for an algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for an algorithm.